# Vim cursor moves forward 7 characters when I use my remapped <Esc>

Tags: vim

I took a stab at writing my own .vimrc for the first time.  I've gotten used to using "kj" as a replacement for Escape so I added a remapping.  Here is a copy of my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

" Plugins
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'sjl/badwolf'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

" Ctrl P
let g:ctrlp_atch_window = 'bottom,order:ttb'
let g:ctrlp_switch_buffer = 0
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0

" Syntastic
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

let g:syntastic_js_checkers = ['jshint']

" Fugitive
set statusline+=%{fugitive#statusline()}

" Vim Airline
set laststatus=2

" Colors
syntax enable
colorscheme badwolf
let g:badwolf_darkgutter=1

" Misc
set ttyfast
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" Spaces & Tabs
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent

" UI Layout
set number
set showcmd
set cursorline
set wildmenu
set showmatch
match Error /\%81v.\+/

" Searching
set ignorecase
set incsearch
set hlsearch

" Folding
" set foldmethod=indent
" set foldnestmax=10
" set foldenable
" nnoremap <space> za
" set foldlevelstart=10

" Shortcut Remmaping
inoremap kj <Esc>       
vnoremap kj <Esc>

" Movement
" nnoremap <buffer> <silent> j gj
" nnoremap <buffer> <silent> k gk
map <C-h> :wincmd h<CR>
map <C-j> :wincmd j<CR>
map <C-k> :wincmd k<CR>
map <C-l> :wincmd l<CR>

" Leader Shortcuts
let mapleader=","
let g:mapleader=","
nnoremap <leader>w :NERDTree<CR>
nnoremap <leader>l :call ToggleNumber()<CR>
nnoremap <leader><space> <silent> :nohlsearch<CR>
nnoremap <leader>t :TagbarToggle<CR>

" Custom Functions
function! ToggleNumber()
  if(&relativenumber == 1)
    set norelativenumber
    set number
  else
    set relativenumber
  endif
endfunc

" Return to last edit position when opening files (You want this!)
autocmd BufReadPost *
     \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
     \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
     \ endif
" Remember info about open buffers on close
set viminfo^=%
```

When I include the "kj" remappings upon pressing "kj" while in insert mode, I enter normal mode and then my cursor moves forwards 7 characters.  Without the remapping the letters are simply be typed into the buffer.

I have tried disabling all of my plugins, but the problem still persists.  This is driving me mad, any ideas what could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are trailing spaces right after `inoremap kj <Esc>`, which is interpreted as a part of the mapping. Try removing these spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was driving me insane.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can avoid this type of error in my .vimrc again?

Comment: @a240 Sorry to be late. You can highlight trailing spaces with vim. There are several ways to do this, such as: I) use `set list` and `listchar`. II) [Use `matchadd` and highlight white spaces yourself](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces), III) Use fancy plugins, such as https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace.